# Управление касанием по экрану UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d

Решил сделать простой мультипллеерный пинг понг на unity. Сделал для ПК но не знаю как сделать на андроид.
Но не могу сделать управление ракеткой вверх и вниз. Хотел бы сделать так что бы если игрок нажимает на нижнюю часть экрана то ракетка двигается вниз а если касается верхней то ракетка двигается наверх.
Вот код управление ракеткой:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Racket : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private GameCamera gameCamera;
    [SyncVar] private int playerNumber;

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 0.1f;
    [SyncVar(hook = "OnPointsChanged")] private int points;
    public int Points
    {
        get { return points; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0 && points != value)
                points = value;
        }
    }

    private void OnPointsChanged(int points)
    {
        gameCamera.UpdateUI(playerNumber, points);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
            return;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y < GameCamera.Size.y - transform.localScale.y / 2) 
            transform.Translate(0, speed, 0);
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y > -GameCamera.Size.y + transform.localScale.y / 2)
            transform.Translate(0, -speed, 0);
    }

    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
        base.OnStartLocalPlayer();

        if (isServer)
            playerNumber = 1;
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        gameCamera = Camera.main.GetComponent<GameCamera>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Создайте 2 кнопки: 1 в верхнюю половину, второй в нижнюю и прикрепите к ним функции. В чём проблема?

Comment: какие функции вот в чем вопрос

Comment: Вы же сказали что уже написали для компьютера. Вот эти функции поставьте на кнопки.